# How to create a .txt file in python by the user prefered nsme?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-3.4, python-import, python-3.3

I have made a program tht reads the stored file details.
I want to create a .txt file using  python tkinter .the name of the creating file will be given by user in entry box.

Can you provide the correct code.please

Comment: `f = open("filename.txt", 'w")` and `f.write("Hello World!\n")`.  That's all.

Comment: This will create a file with name "filename.txt"

Comment: But i want the user to provide the name not the progtammer

Comment: I was thinking you know how to get text from entry box and use it in place of "filename.txt"

Comment: `name = your_entry.get()` and `f = open(name, "w") `, that's all.

Comment: Ys i did the same but it's not working ... It creates a .txt file with no nsme

Comment: so show your code in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def clicked():
    Input = entry1.get()
    FileName = str("filepath" + Input + ".txt")
    TextFile = open(FileName,"w")

entry1 = Entry(root)
button1 = Button(root,text="Press to create text file", command = clicked)
entry1.pack()
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will make a function that runs when the button is clicked, it will get the text in the entry box then make a file path, finally it will attempt to open this file, as the file doesn't exist it will instead create a new file under this name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
import tkinter as tk

def write_file():
    name = e.get() # get text from entry
    with open(name + ".txt", "w") as f: # open file 
        f.write("Hello World\n") # write doesn't add '\n'
    # `with` will close file automatically

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack() # can't be `e = Widget(...).pack()`

tk.Button(root, text="Save", command=write_file).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: After i run this code it produces undesirable output... No entry box ... Just a button displaying "" hello"" after i click on ... It fives a message box "hellow world""

Comment: it is impossible. What do you use ?  it works for me on Linux with Python 3.4 and Python 2.7.

Comment: I use Windows..  With python 2.7